# byte[] as an input for a rest web service

Tags: java, rest, web, service

having problems with the following. i can't seems to pass in the byte[] created from a file into a web service. when i execute my client code, the server log throwing nullpointer for the pdfFile byte[]. please assists here.

**Server side:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadForMarkPDF", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { "application/octet-stream" })
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> pdfMark(@RequestParam(value = "pdfFile", required = false)  byte[] pdfFile) {

        try {

            log.info("inside pdf Mark");

            log.info("passed in file size:"+pdfFile.length);
.
.
.
```

**client side:**

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = null;
        byte[] data = null;
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/legacyRest/uploadForMarkPDF";

        File pdfFile = new File("C:\\watermarktest\\form.pdf");

        Path fileLocation = Paths.get("C:\\watermarktest\\form.pdf");

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
        post.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream; boundary=\"---Content Boundary\"");
        try {
            data = Files.readAllBytes(fileLocation);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

        multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("pdfFile", data, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"),
                "pdfFile");
        multipartEntityBuilder.setBoundary("---Content Boundary");
        httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpEntity entity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
        post.setEntity(entity);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);

            System.out.println(response);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println(responseEntity);

            InputStream responseStream = responseEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: your multipartEntityBuilder.build() is building nothing. hence a null requestparam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is client-side and a misunderstanding of the Builder.

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create(); // init builder

multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("pdfFile", data, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"),
            "pdfFile");
multipartEntityBuilder.setBoundary("---Content Boundary");
HttpEntity entity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
```

This implementation is along the same lines of just doing

```
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().build();
```

The builder pattern sets a field and return the builder. This would give you the ability to chain builders together. However, if you do not chain the builders, you would need to make sure that you keep a reference to the return object of the builder since these hold the fields you're hoping to populate.

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntityBuilder = multipartEntityBuilder.setBoundary("---Content Boundary");
```

However, this would be the preferred approach.

```
HttpEntity entity = MultiPartEntityBuilder.create().set*(*).set*(*).build()
```

Comment: thanks for the response shin! i tried httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
  HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE).addBinaryBody("pdfFile", data, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"), pdfFile.getName()).build();
  
  
  post.setEntity(entity);

  try {
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post); i.e. grouping the builders together, but to no avail. it still can't get the value out from the server side of the variable name pdfFile.

Comment: Is there something besides a NPE thrown now?

Comment: unfortunately no other errors available:INFO : com.maxis.legacyRest.WatermarkService - inside pdf Mark
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.maxis.legacyRest.WatermarkService.pdfMark(WatermarkService.java:63)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: hang on a second, i am checking the byte[] that i am sending in on this. thanks for ur help thus far shin.